# How to display the Form properly?

Tags: django, django-forms

I just want to show a Form on a HTML Page. 
When I put it on the Page and look via Web Browser, there seems to show me the memory address instead of rendering the form..

[forms.py]

```py
from django import forms

MODES=[('top10', 'Top 10 Songs'),
    ('last10', 'Last 10 Songs'),
    ('recentX', 'Recent X Songs')]

class chooseMode():
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    selectMode = forms.ChoiceField(label='Choose Mode', widget=forms.RadioSelect,choices=MODES)
```

[views.py]

```py
def home(request):
    modusFormular = chooseMode()

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'modusForm' : modusFormular})
```

[home.html]
somewhere in body: 
{{ modusForm }}

I expected the form to be shown on the page, but it shows me the following:

```
<mysongproject.forms.chooseMode object at 0x7fcdcae97710>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class needs to inherit from Form:

```
class chooseMode(forms.Form):
```